# jQuery or javascript prevent event from input keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

CODE:

```js
var appender = $('<input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search_made" type="text">')
appender.find('#search_made').on('keypress', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('keypress!')
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    console.log('not shift enter')
    var passed_value = $(this).val()
    if (passed_value === '') {
      console.log('nothing was passed on input tag')
      return false;
    }
    console.log('passed value: ' + passed_value)
  }
})

$('body').append(appender)
```

I want to add `input` tag dynamically by jQuery.

Using those code, I can only add input tag seemingly but other functions that has to be bound was not bound well.

So when I type some words on input tag and click `enter key`, It refreshes page but does not execute any `console.log()` lines.

How can I fix it to make it do other bound functions(include `console.log()`) well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the selector from:

```
appender.find('#search_made').on('keypress', function(e) {
```

To

```
$(document).on('keypress','#search_made', function(e) {
```

OR: Simply

```
appender.on('keypress', function(e) {
```

**Working Code Example:**

```js
var appender = $('<input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search_made" type="text">')
$(document).on('keypress','#search_made', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('keypress!')
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    console.log('not shift enter')
    var passed_value = $(this).val()
    if (passed_value === '') {
      console.log('nothing was passed on input tag')
      return false;
    }
    console.log('passed value: ' + passed_value)
  }
})

$('body').append(appender)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: or just `appender.on(`

Comment: @dgeare, added that as part of the answer.....thanks for helping me to improve the answer.